# Does $\int \frac{1}{u} \frac{du}{dt} dt$ violate integration by parts?

Tags: calculus

Given that $u = u(t)$, does $\int \frac{1}{u} \frac{du}{dt} dt$ violate integration by parts, since the equation below is not possible?

$$ \int \frac{1}{u} \frac{du}{dt} dt = \frac{1}{u} u - \int u \left(-\frac{1}{u^2} \frac{du}{dt} \right)dt$$

$$ \therefore 0 = 1$$

Also, 
$$\int f(u) \frac{du}{dt} dt = \int \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}[f(u)]^2\ dt = \frac{1}{2} [f(u)]^2$$

but if $f(u)=1/u$, the equation above gives

$$\int f(u) \frac{du}{dt} dt = \frac{1}{2u^2}$$
which is not true.

What is happening with this function?

Comment: It's somewhat tricky to read your notation.  But indefinite integrals are defined up to constants.  So, I think that you've shown that $1=C$.

Comment: Also, isn't $(1/2)d/dt[f(u)]^2 = f(u)f'(u) du/dt$?

Comment: Actually, the answer should be $ln|u| + C$, where $C$ can be any constant value, not necessarily 1.

Comment: As others have stated, the indefinite integral is a family of functions, each of which differ from the others by a constant values.  So, $1$ and $0$ are equivalent within a constant.  All is OK.

Comment: What is happening is that you have written $\frac{\mathsf du}{\mathsf dt}$ as though it were a function to be integrated. I think this is an abuse of notation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\frac{du}{dt}dt=du$.  So, simplifying what you're writing comes to:
$$
\int \frac{1}{u}du.
$$
Then, you do integration by parts with $f=\frac{1}{u}$ and $g'=du$.  Then, $f'=-\frac{1}{u^2}du$ and $g=u$.  In this case, the integration by parts comes to
$$
\int\frac{1}{u}du=1+\int\frac{1}{u}du.
$$
Now, this looks problematic, but it can be resolved by supposing that $F(u)$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{u}$.  In this case, the expression simplifies to
$$
(F(u)+C_1)=1+(F(u)+C_2)
$$
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants of integration.  Therefore, $1=C_1-C_2$, which is not a problem.  The issue is that $\int\frac{1}{u}du$ can represent two different functions in the same equation.

Note that if you instead used a definite integral, then you would have
$$
\int_a^b\frac{1}{u}du=\left.1\right|_a^b+\int_a^b\frac{1}{u}du.
$$
Moreover $\left.1\right|_a^b=1-1=0$, so this simplifies to
$$
\int_a^b\frac{1}{u}du=\int_a^b\frac{1}{u}du.
$$
Once the $1$ vanishes, this might make you feel a bit more comfortable.

In the second example, there is a missing chain rule.
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}[f(u)]^2\not=f(u)\frac{du}{dt},
$$
but
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}[f(u)]^2=f(u)f'(u)\frac{du}{dt}.
$$
You're missing a derivative of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, it does really explain the "0 = 1" part of the problem. But what about the second part that says that $\int (1/u\ du/dt)\ dt = 1/(2u^2)$?

Comment: Additionally, the simplification $(du/dt)\ dt = du$ doesn't seem a rigorous mathematical procedure to me (I'm not a mathematician, so I'm not sure), since $d/dt$ and $\int dt$ are operators and not variables. Is there a way of solving this integral without using this simplification?

Comment: There is a theorem that $\frac{d}{dt}(u)=\frac{du}{dt}$.  In other words, the derivative operator applied to the function $u$ is the same as the quotient of two differentials.  The full answer is much too long to fit into a comment (and could be asked in a different question).  For more details on this equality, see the chain rule part of the [Properties of the Differential of a Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Properties).  For your second question, you have a missing chain rule, I've edited my answer.